# List Operator Precedence in Perl

Tags: perl, operator-precedence

I'm reading the "Beginning Perl" book, and it gives these two statements:

```
print "Test one: ", 6 > 3 && 3 > 4, "\n";
print "Test two: ", 6 > 3 and 3 > 4, "\n";
```

The first line prints nothing with a new line, the second line prints a 1 with no new line.

I'm confused about the output. According to the author, the second statement gives weird output because it's just like saying:

```
print ("Test two: ", 6 > 3) and 3 > 4, "\n";
```

However, why is the first statement not the same? I thought it had something to do with print's precedence. The && has higher precedence than print, so that's evaluated first and then it's printed. Whereas the "and" has lower precedence than print, so 6 > 3 will be printed, print returns a 1, and then that is evaluated with the "and." However this doesn't really make sense.

I've read the Perl documentation on how precedence works for list operators, but I still do not understand this example. Can you guys dissect the two statements, and tell me what is printed first? Can you also explain what the Perl documentation means when it mentions list operators as being "leftward" and "rightward?" Thanks.

---

Thanks a lot everyone for your answers. I understand it now. I was indeed doing what cjm said, and thinking that there are leftward and rightward list operators. So now that I understand what it means, I understand the whole thing.

Comment: this code prints warnings. and has even funner behavior in Devel::REPL

Comment: @xenoterracide, it's not intended to be good Perl code.  It's just trying to illustrate how precedence works.

Comment: @cjm right... although re.pl's behavior seemed wrong enough for me to file a bug on it. we'll see what comes of that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, for starters: list-operators are among the lowest-precedence things in perl, but *only on their right side*. You ask what that means: well, let's make it simple. Suppose that there is a listop called `foo`. It doesn't matter what it does, but it's there. You can easily create such a thing with `sub foo { map 10 * $_, @_ }` which returns each of its arguments multiplied by ten. That out of the way:

`print 1, 2, 3;` is equivalent to `print( 1, 2, 3 );`
`print foo 1, 2, 3;` is equivalent to `print( foo( 1, 2, 3 ) );`
`print 1, foo 2, 3;` is equivalent to `print( 1, foo( 2, 3 ) );`

We can see that `foo` gobbles up as much as it can on the right side — only the end of the statement (so far...) can stop it. If we wrote `@array = (1, foo 2, 3);` that would be equivalent to `@array = (1, foo(2, 3) );` because of course ending surrounding parentheses still applies.

Since commas are also very low priority (just above "List operators (rightward)"), we can also put pretty much any kind of expression we want into the arguments to a listop — this is just perl's way of making sure that we don't have to add parentheses most of the time. Math, bitwise operators, comparisons, even regex matches have higher priority.

The only things that *do* have lower-priority are the spelled-out logical connectives `and`, `or`, `xor`, and `not`. So if we write

```
foo 1, 2, 3 and 4;
```

that means `(foo(1, 2, 3) and 4)` -- the arguments to `foo` stop to the left of the `and`. This  seems silly in a contrived example, so let's turn it into a common perl idiom:

```
open $fh, '<', $filename or die "$! opening $filename";
```

which is equivalent to

```
(open($fh, '<', $filename) or die("$! opening $filename"));
```

which is actually exactly equivalent to (and compiles to)

```
die "$! opening $filename" unless open $fh, '<', $filename;
```

using the statement-modifier form of `unless` (which isn't an operator at all, is allowed only once per statement, and only comes at the end of a statement, so it doesn't really engage in precedence at all, but you could consider it as "lower than lowest" precedence leftwards).

So anyway, returning to your original code sample -- the arguments to `print` end just left of the `and`, and to the right of the `and` is a completely separate comma expression — which does nothing at all because it's just a few constants `3 > 4` and `"\n"` evaluated in void context.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how those statements would look with full parentheses:

```
print("Test one: ", ((6 > 3) && (3 > 4)), "\n");
print("Test two: ", (6 > 3)) and ((3 > 4), "\n");
```

`>` has the highest precedence, then `&&`, then `,`, then `print`, then `and`.

`6 > 3` evaluates to `1`.  `3 > 4` evaluates to false, which in Perl is a special value that is 0 in a numeric context but the empty string in a string context (like here).  So `((6 > 3) && (3 > 4))` yields the empty string.

Thus, the first statement passes 3 arguments to `print`: `"Test one: "`, the empty string, and a newline.  It prints each argument in order.

The second statement passes only 2 arguments to `print`: `"Test two: "` and `1`.  The newline doesn't get printed because it never got passed to `print`.

I'm not sure how to explain "leftward" and "rightward" better than [the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Terms-and-List-Operators-%28Leftward%29).  But maybe what's confusing you is that you're thinking there are "leftward list ops" and "rightward list ops".  That's not what it means.  It's trying to say that everything on the right-hand side of a list operator gets interpreted as the arguments for that operator (unless you hit one of the very-low-precedence Boolean operators like `and`).  But things on the left-hand side of a list operator are not associated with that list operator.

Comment: @hobbs: In what way is it not correct?  musikk and I said the same thing, except I used some extra parens (and his now-retracted claim that `3 > 4` is `undef`).  The output of `perl -MO=Deparse,-p` is identical for the original statements versus my fully-parenthesized versions.

Comment: How does this work in the case of file test operators? For example, using [`Test::More`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More) I wrote this test `ok( not -e $fn, 'file does not exists' )` which does the opposite of what I expected..

Comment: @HåkonHægland, the file test operators are [named unary operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Named-Unary-Operators), not list operators.  But it's the extremely-low-precedence `not` that's causing your problem, not the `-e`.  Try using `! -e` instead.

Answer (score 4):

It is as you say, except for the "this doesn't make sense" part.

The first is

```
print "Test one: ", (6 > 3 && 3 > 4), "\n";
```

and the second

```
(print "Test two: ", 6 > 3) and (3 > 4, "\n");
```

If you turn on warnings (`use warnings`) you get the warning `Useless use of a constant in void context` because the right side of the `and` evaluates to a list with elements *false* and a newline but isn't ever used.

**edit**: Corrected my *3>4 is undef* claim. False is not undef. It's defined and prints nothing.