# Perl operator precendece for a combination of list and unary operators

Tags: perl, operators, operator-precedence

I came across an odd case, related to operator precendence, I guess. Consider this test program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

my $fn = 'dummy';
ok( ! -e $fn, 'file does not exists' );
ok( not -e $fn, 'file does not exists' );
done_testing();
```

The output is:

```
ok 1 - file does not exists
not ok 2
#   Failed test at ./p.pl line 10.
1..2
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
```

The question is: Why does the second test fail? (`$fn` is assumed known to be non-existent)

See also: [List Operator Precedence in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437935/list-operator-precedence-in-perl/3438126#comment56266649_3438126).

---

After reading [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), my guess is that at least five operators could be involved here:

- [Terms and List Operators (Leftward)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Terms-and-List-Operators-(Leftward))
- [List Operators (Rightward)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#List-Operators-(Rightward))
- [Named Unary Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Named-Unary-Operators)
- [Logical Not](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Not)
- [Comma Operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the second test fail?

Because Perl's parser handles `!` and `not` differently. You can see this in Perl's grammar, which is defined in [perly.y](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.22.0/perly.y) in the Perl source.

The rule for `!` kicks in as soon as the parser encounters a `!` followed by a term:

```
    |       '!' term                               /* !$x */
                    { $$ = newUNOP(OP_NOT, 0, scalar($2)); }
```

On the other hand, the rule for `not` only kicks in when the parser encounters a `not` followed by a list expression (a list of terms joined by commas*):

```
    |       NOTOP listexpr                       /* not $foo */
                    { $$ = newUNOP(OP_NOT, 0, scalar($2)); }
```

Note that the action for both rules is the same: add a new unary opcode of type `OP_NOT` to the parse tree. The operand is the second argument (`term` or `listexpr`) in scalar context.

---

<sup>* Or a single term, but this has very low precedence.</sup>

## Tracing the parse

You can see the above rules in action by compiling perl with `-DDEBUGGING` and running with `-Dpv`, which turns on [debug flags](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-D*_number_) for tokenizing and parsing.

Here's what the parser does with `!`:

```
$ perl -Dpv -e'ok(! -e "foo", "bar")'
...

Next token is token '(' (0x1966e98)
Shifting token '(', Entering state 185
Reading a token:
Next token is token '!' (0x1966e98)
Shifting token '!', Entering state 49
Reading a token:
Next token is token UNIOP (0x110)
Shifting token UNIOP, Entering state 39
Reading a token:
Next token is token THING (0x1966e58)
Shifting token THING, Entering state 25

index:        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9
state:        8       15      103       68      185       49       39       25
token:       @1 remember  stmtseq    amper      '('      '!'    UNIOP    THING
value:        0       22 (Nullop)    rv2cv 26635928 26635928      272    const

Reducing stack by rule 184 (line 961), THING -> term
Entering state 128
Reading a token:
Next token is token ',' (0x1966e58)

index:        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9
state:        8       15      103       68      185       49       39      128
token:       @1 remember  stmtseq    amper      '('      '!'    UNIOP     term
value:        0       22 (Nullop)    rv2cv 26635928 26635928      272    const

Reducing stack by rule 199 (line 999), UNIOP term -> term
Entering state 150
Next token is token ',' (0x1966e58)

index:        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8
state:        1        8       15      103       68      185       49      150
token: GRAMPROG       @1 remember  stmtseq    amper      '('      '!'     term
value:        0        0       22 (Nullop)    rv2cv 26635928 26635928     ftis

Reducing stack by rule 148 (line 829), '!' term -> termunop
Entering state 62

index:        1        2        3        4        5        6        7
state:        1        8       15      103       68      185       62
token: GRAMPROG       @1 remember  stmtseq    amper      '(' termunop
value:        0        0       22 (Nullop)    rv2cv 26635928      not

...
```

In other words, the parser reads in

```
( ! -e "foo"
```

reduces `-e "foo"` to a `term`, and then adds a logical negation opcode to the parse tree. The operand is `-e "foo"` in scalar context.

---

Here's what the parser does with `not`:

```
$ perl -Dpv -e'ok(not -e "foo", "bar")'
...

Reading a token:
Next token is token '(' (0x26afed8)
Shifting token '(', Entering state 185
Reading a token:
Next token is token NOTOP (0x26afed8)
Shifting token NOTOP, Entering state 48
Reading a token:
Next token is token UNIOP (0x110)
Shifting token UNIOP, Entering state 39
Reading a token:
Next token is token THING (0x26afe98)
Shifting token THING, Entering state 25

index:        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9
state:        8       15      103       68      185       48       39       25
token:       @1 remember  stmtseq    amper      '('    NOTOP    UNIOP    THING
value:        0       22 (Nullop)    rv2cv 40566488 40566488      272    const

Reducing stack by rule 184 (line 961), THING -> term
Entering state 128
Reading a token:
Next token is token ',' (0x26afe98)

index:        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9
state:        8       15      103       68      185       48       39      128
token:       @1 remember  stmtseq    amper      '('    NOTOP    UNIOP     term
value:        0       22 (Nullop)    rv2cv 40566488 40566488      272    const

Reducing stack by rule 199 (line 999), UNIOP term -> term
Entering state 65
Next token is token ',' (0x26afe98)

index:        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8
state:        1        8       15      103       68      185       48       65
token: GRAMPROG       @1 remember  stmtseq    amper      '('    NOTOP     term
value:        0        0       22 (Nullop)    rv2cv 40566488 40566488     ftis

Reducing stack by rule 105 (line 683), term -> listexpr
Entering state 149
Next token is token ',' (0x26afe98)
Shifting token ',', Entering state 162
Reading a token:
Next token is token THING (0x26afdd8)
Shifting token THING, Entering state 25

index:        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10
state:       15      103       68      185       48      149      162       25
token: remember  stmtseq    amper      '('    NOTOP listexpr      ','    THING
value:       22 (Nullop)    rv2cv 40566488 40566488     ftis 40566424    const

Reducing stack by rule 184 (line 961), THING -> term
Entering state 249
Reading a token:
Next token is token ')' (0x26afdd8)

index:        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10
state:       15      103       68      185       48      149      162      249
token: remember  stmtseq    amper      '('    NOTOP listexpr      ','     term
value:       22 (Nullop)    rv2cv 40566488 40566488     ftis 40566424    const

Reducing stack by rule 104 (line 678), listexpr ',' term -> listexpr
Entering state 149
Next token is token ')' (0x26afdd8)

index:        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8
state:        1        8       15      103       68      185       48      149
token: GRAMPROG       @1 remember  stmtseq    amper      '('    NOTOP listexpr
value:        0        0       22 (Nullop)    rv2cv 40566488 40566488     list

Reducing stack by rule 196 (line 993), NOTOP listexpr -> term
Entering state 65
Next token is token ')' (0x26afdd8)

index:        1        2        3        4        5        6        7
state:        1        8       15      103       68      185       65
token: GRAMPROG       @1 remember  stmtseq    amper      '('     term
value:        0        0       22 (Nullop)    rv2cv 40566488      not

...
```

In other words, the parser reads in

```
( not -e "foo"
```

reduces `-e "foo"` to a `term`, reads in

```
, "bar"
```

reduces `term, "bar"` to a `listexpr`, and then adds a logical negation opcode to the parse tree. The operand is `-e "foo", "bar"` in scalar context.

---

So, even though the opcodes for the two logical negations are the same, their operands are different. You can see this by inspecting the generated parse trees:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-tree -e'ok(! -e "foo", "bar")'
<a>leave[1 ref]-+-<1>enter
                |-<2>nextstate(main 1 -e:1)
                `-<9>entersub[t1]---ex-list-+-<3>pushmark
                                            |-<6>not---<5>ftis---<4>const(PV "foo")
                                            |-<7>const(PV "bar")
                                            `-ex-rv2cv---<8>gv(*ok)
-e syntax OK
$ perl -MO=Concise,-tree -e'ok(not -e "foo", "bar")'
<c>leave[1 ref]-+-<1>enter
                |-<2>nextstate(main 1 -e:1)
                `-<b>entersub[t1]---ex-list-+-<3>pushmark
                                            |-<9>not---<8>list-+-<4>pushmark
                                            |                  |-<6>ftis---<5>const(PV "foo")
                                            |                  `-<7>const(PV "bar")
                                            `-ex-rv2cv---<a>gv(*ok)
-e syntax OK
```

With `!`, the negation acts on the file test:

```
|-<6>not---<5>ftis
```

While with `not`, the negation acts on a list:

```
|-<9>not---<8>list
```

You can also dump the parse tree as Perl code using B::Deparse, which shows the same thing in a different format:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e'ok(! -e "foo", "bar")'
ok((!(-e 'foo')), 'bar');
-e syntax OK
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e'ok(not -e "foo", "bar")'
ok((!((-e 'foo'), 'bar')));
-e syntax OK
```

With `!`, the negation acts on the file test:

```
!(-e 'foo')
```

While with `not`, the negation acts on a list:

```
!((-e 'foo'), 'bar')
```

And as [toolic explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34269666/176646), a list in scalar context evaluates to the last item in the list, giving

```
ok( ! 'bar' );
```

where `! 'bar'` is falsey.

Answer (score 4):

`perl -MO=Deparse` shows that your code is interpreted as:

```
use Test::More;
use warnings;
use strict;
my $fn = 'dummy';
ok !(-e $fn), 'file does not exists';
ok !(-e $fn, 'file does not exists');
done_testing();
```

`-e $fn` is false.

But `'file does not exists'` is essentially true.

So, the list `(-e $fn, 'file does not exists')` is true.

Therefore, `!(...)` is false, and the test fails.

Comment: It would be nice if the answer also could explain how this relates to the documentation in  [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).. Which operators are in use, and what is evaluated first and last and why

Comment: @HåkonHægland *"Which operators are in use"* `!`: logical negation (high precedence); `not`: logical negation (low precedence, generates same opcode as `!`); `-e`: file test operator (a named unary op); `,`: comma operator. *"what is evaluated first and last"* `perl -MO=Concise,-exec` dumps the parse tree in execution order. *"and why"* The precedence of `!` > `-e` > `,` > `not`.

Answer (score 1):

After rereading the [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) documentation, here is what I believe is going on:

```
ok( not -e $fn, 'file does not exists' );
```

Perl parses this statement from left to right. The first thing it encounters is a **function call** (also called a **list operator**, if the function is builtin or uses prototypes and operates on lists). The function call `ok( ... )`. is a described as a `TERM` in the documentation:

> A TERM has the highest precedence in Perl. They include variables,
>   quote and quote-like operators, any expression in parentheses, and any
>   **function** whose arguments are parenthesized.

A **list operator** (not accurately defined in the [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) page, but briefly mentioned in the [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) page) is also regarded as a `TERM` if followed by parenthesis. The [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) says:

> If any **list operator** (print(), etc.) or any unary operator (chdir(),
>   etc.) is followed by a left parenthesis as the next token, the
>   operator and arguments within parentheses are taken to be of highest
>   precedence, just like a normal function call.

Now the parser continues with the expression `not -e $fn, 'file does not exists'`. That is, it must resolve the arguments to the `ok` function.
The first thing it encounters here is the `not` operator. The documentation says:

> Unary "not" returns the logical negation of the expression to its
>   right. It's the equivalent of "!" except for the very low precedence.

Then it must determine `"the expression to its right"`. Here, the parser finds the file test operator `-e`. The documentation says:

> Regarding precedence, the filetest operators, like `-f` , `-M` , etc. are
>   treated like named **unary operators**, but they don't follow this
>   functional parenthesis rule. That means, for example, that
>   `-f($file).".bak"` is equivalent to `-f "$file.bak"` .

and

> The various named **unary operators** are treated as functions with one
>   argument, with optional parentheses.

Now the **unary operators** (without a following parenthesis) have higher precendence than the `not` operator, so the parser continues, trying to determine the argument of the `-e` operator. It now encounters a new `TERM`, (we are now considering this expression: `$fn, 'file does not exists'` ). The `TERM` is `$fn` and since `TERM`s have the highest precedence, it is evaluated immediately. Then it continues to the comma operator. Since the comma operator has lower precedence than the filetest operator, and the filetest operator is unary (only takes a single argument), the parser decides it is finished with the argument of the filetest operator and evaluates `-e $fn`. Then it proceeds with the comma:

> Binary "," is the comma operator. In scalar context it evaluates its
>   left argument, throws that value away, then evaluates its right
>   argument and returns that value. This is just like C's comma operator.
>   In list context, it's just the list argument separator, and inserts
>   both its arguments into the list. These arguments are also evaluated
>   from left to right.

Since the comma operator has higher precedence than the `not` operator the parser finds it is still not finished with the argument of `not`. Instead it discovers that the argument of `not` is a list (due to the comma operator), it has already evaluated the left argument of the comma operator, `-e $fn`, and discards that value, and proceeds with the right argument of the comma operator which is the string `'file does not exists'`. This is evaluated, and the parser then finds the closing parenthesis `)`, which means that the argument of `not` is the latter string. Negating a nonempty string is false.

And finally, the parser finds that the argument to the `ok` function is false, and runs `ok( 0 )`.

Answer (score 0):

To relate directly to perlop, all you need to notice is that `!` is above `,` is above `not` in the table:

```
       right       ! ~ \ and unary + and -
...
       left        , =>
...
       right       not
```

That is, the comma binds things together "more tightly" than `not` does, but "less tightly" than `!` does.

Comment: Hmm.. there is also a file test operator, a list operator, and more I think.. You say `"all you need to notice"`.. why is that? Could you relate it more specifically to the documentation